# Running API's in parallel on same server

Tags: python, api, amazon-web-services, parallel-processing

I have 4 APIs which I want to run in parallel on an AWS box with 16GB RAM and 8 CPUs. Can I run those APIs in parallel using python's Flask?

Basically, I want one of the APIs to take in user input and then query 3 other APIs in parallel.

I am new to the paradigm of APIs and parallel processing so any sort of help will be highly appreciated.

Here is what I am thinking:

```
import requests
r1 = requests.get(url_of_api1, data).json()
r2 = requests.get(url_of_api2, data).json()
r3 = requests.get(url_of_api3, data).json()
```

I want r1, r2 and r3 to be queried in parallel and not one after the other. How can this be done?

Comment: Do you have a specific code question?  Can you post your code snippet so far?

Comment: **API** stands for [Application Programming Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface).  It's a very abstract concept and your use of the term only makes your question more vague. There are many ways to implement an API, but I believe you're asking about hosting multiple Web APIs on the same machine. Is this correct?

Comment: @Balrog30 - thats correct!! Thats exactly what I want. I have converted my python programs into APIs using Flask and now I want to host multiple APIs on the same machine.

Comment: I don't know the details of Python or Flask, but there are three language-independent ways to do this, that I am aware of.  1) Put them all in the same program/process and separate them by adding to the beginning of the url routes. 2) Make them different processes listening on different ports. 3) Have some software layer (internal or external) handle actually listening to the port and route to each API by having a separate DNS address for each.  Not sure if this helps you at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be the parallel code using threads.

```
import requests
import concurrent.futures

t = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(3) # 3 is the number of threads

get_json_from_url = lambda url: requests.get(url, data).json()

r1, r2, r3 = t.map(get_json_from_url, [url_of_api1, url_of_api2, url_of_api3])
```

Comment: can it be done in Python 2.7? Also, can number of threads be greater than number of CPUs that my machine has?

Comment: @mousecoder Yes, it can be done. I checked, there is the `concurrent.futures` module, also in Python 2.7.

Comment: I could not find it. I ended up installing python3 finally.